# I can't connect to SQL Server when I use a domain name

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I am able to connect to my MS SQL Server remotely (on our VPN) when I use its IP address, but not when I use a domain name pointing to that IP address (from a DDNS service). I'm using HeidiSQL as a client.

Does SQL Server need to be configured to allow me to use the domain name instead of the IP address? (Can it tell the difference?)

Comment: Can you access SQL with a local account? Preferably a SQL admin account?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Or over the LAN. Or over the VPN with just an IP address.

Comment: Can you ping the domainname while connected to your VPN?

Comment: That ended up being a key question. I've started a new thread (http://serverfault.com/questions/818532/cant-do-a-dns-lookup-for-a-ddns-from-my-computer).